# Is there any way in NSFileManager to get contents of a file only for some range of bytes

Tags: iphone, ios, file-io, nsfilemanager, fseek

I have some files that are of size 6.7GB, and more (these are video files).
I want to get chunks of file data to send to my server, so what I currently do is :

```
contents = [fileManager contentsAtPath:path];
if (mFileOffset<[contents length]) {
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(mFileOffset, (allowedSize>[contents length]?[contents length]:allowedSize);
contents =[contents subdataWithRange:range];
```

However, this produces a memory issue:

```
malloc: *** mmap(size=616927232) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
APP(2700,0x4136000) malloc: *** mmap(size=616927232) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
```

Is there a way like `fseek` in `c++` so that I read bytes of the file that come in the specified range only?

Comment: fseek should be available just FYI.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: I want something in Obj-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method in [NSFileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which synchronously reads data up to the specified number of bytes.

```
-[NSFileHandle readDataOfLength:]
```

For seeking :

```
– offsetInFile
– seekToEndOfFile
– seekToFileOffset:
```

Comment: how do i read file from a particular point. For example, if my file is of size 5 MB, and I want to read from 200KB to 400KB?

Comment: `NSFileHandle` has a `seekToFileOffset` method :-)

Comment: @NikitaP: Please see the edit and do read the nsfileHandle documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`fseek` is not `C++`, it's a `C` function. The same function is available in `Obj-C`.

Note that `Obj-C` is only a layer over `C` and every valid `C` code is also a valid `Obj-C` code.

The file functions are also abstracted into an `Obj-C` class `NSFileHandle`. However, this class has exactly the same functionality as `fopen`, `fseek`, `fclose` etc.

Comment: Sultan sir, I always tried to run from C-file handling but I loved C++ seekg seekp etc, c++ has much easier, but now in obj-c that is even easier than iostream and all, what you say?